# Is their an excel function to compare two list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two lists. The list on the left contains the numbers of jersey numbers that are not available anymore, on the right side I have the numbers from 1-99. I want to display true or false if the list on the left contains one of the numbers.

I used the following formula, but it is not working

=IF(E2=H2,TRUE,False)

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: `COUNTIF` will do ;)

Comment: Also, to compare two lists and check if any value in list1 is contained in list2 you can try the following array entered formula: `=SUM(COUNTIF(List1,List2))>0`

Comment: Do you want *True* if **one and only one** item matches or if **at least one** item matches ??

Comment: I added the wrong formula. I want to iterate over the entire list 

=IF(E2:E29=H6,TRUE,False). 

But this is not working and I also tried with COUNTIF

Comment: `=IF(condition,TRUE,FALSE)` can be simplified to `=condition`.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me get it straight? you want to see if one value in the second list is already in first list or not?, then count if should work perfectly fine.
Put this formula on I2 then drag down, should work fine.

```
IF(COUNTIF(E$2:E$29,H2)>0,True,False)
```